# How to design a Redux Store for a list which maintains the selection state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

My Components

```
'List'
'ListItem' (shows item selected or not)
```

Thinking to have the following structure for store

```
store : {
 entities : {
   orders : []
 },
 selectedOrders : [ orderId1, orderId2 ]
}
```

So every time action is dispatched **ListItem** component has to check if its ID is present in the **selectedOrders** and then show the appropriate selection state, isn't it bad for the performance iterating every time **selectedOrders**?

Comment: you could iterate over orders and use `selectedOrder.includes(id)`. performance is no issue for small states like this. just keep a flat and prevent deep objects.

Answer (score 1):

I think that nothing wrong with iterating through an array. Especially if it is not particularly big. I think it is better to optimize for readability than performance first.

That said you can use more efficient data structures. Like objects. Use the ids as keys and the values are does not matter as long as they are truthy. For example:

```
selectedOrders : { orderId1: true, orderId2: true }
```

And the checking is fast:

```
selectedOrders['orderId1']
```

Adding and removing keys are a little trickier:
Adding:

```
selectedOrders: {...state.selectedOrders, [order]: true}
```

Removing:

```
selectedOrders: state.selectedOrders.filter(o => o !== order)
```

You can even use Set, but I do not know it is pariculary supported in Redux state or not.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to do that. There is no trick that can prevent you from that. As commented by `oshell`, it is better to maintain an array with `id`'s only. And use a simple operation like:

```
selectedOrder.includes(id); //true
```

or if you really want to have object's in your `selectedOrder` then a better way is:

```
selectedOrder.some(order => order.id === id); //true
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to you read [Official Redux documentation](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape/)